# Atom editor and embedded perl: syntax highlighting

Tags: perl, atom-editor, mojolicious

I am using the atom text editor to write Perl and I would like to have proper syntax highlighting and indentation for the template system used by the Mojolicious framework called Embedded Perl. I have tried to enable the Perl syntax manually in Atom but this does not create automatic indentation when I for instance create a <div> element. So it does not work properly for the Embedded Perl files (html.ep).

How do I bind a syntax highlighting to a specific file extension such that atom automatically associates an extension with a syntax and where can I find a syntax highlighter for atom for Embedded Perl?

If no such syntax highlighter exists, can you perhaps point me in the direction of how to write one myself?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow and the Perl tag. I feel with you, but I believe this might be a better fit for [superuser.com](http://superuser.com). If you don't get answers here, you should try there. At least on the writing it yourself part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should have been easy to find with the Atom package search feature. https://github.com/kraih/atom-mojo

Comment: Got it. Thank you. For some reason I was searching for "embedded perl" and perl only. I didn't think that there was a Mojolicious syntax highlighter.

To answer my other question about associating an extension with a syntax: Go to Settings -> Open config Folder -> .atom/packages/language-mojolicious/grammars/perl (mojolicious templates).json -> find "fileTypes" and add the needed extensions there.

Comment: I could use a bit more syntax highlighting on the HTML, though. HTML comments could be highlighted and so could HTML attributes and values.